# Unable to read file from sd card in Android

Tags: java, android, file, file-handling

I am trying to read a file from sdcard using the following code

```
     f = new RandomAccessFile("/storage/sdcard0/trac.txt", "r");
```

But the app crashes while doing so. I am able to create and write a file in sdcard but unable to read it.
I have following permissions in my manifest and i am running it as a system app:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: post the crash log. are you sure the path is correct?

Comment: I am trying to remember the exact details, but I believe that if you run under a shared userid with the system you will be prohibited from utlizing the external storage for legacy reasons having to do with processes being killed on unmounting - so you might test this code in an ordinary app and see if it works there.  More generally, you should be determining the storage path at runtime rather than guessing it.  It would be helpful to show the writing code which you seem to be implying works, and as already requested the actual log of the crash.

Answer (score -1):

Try getting your sd card path by doing this:

```
String yourpath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                             .getAbsolutePath() + "/folderName/";
```

Comment: This returns /storage/emulated/0 not /sdcard

Answer (score -1):

```
try {
                File myFile = new File("/sdcard/mysdfile.txt");
                FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(myFile);
                BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(fIn));
                String fileStr= "";
                String aBuffer = "";
                while ((fileStr= myReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    aBuffer += fileStr+ "\n";
                }
                txtData.setText(aBuffer);
                myReader.close();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "Done reading SD 'mysdfile.txt'",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Its helpful for me.
To more detail :

[How to read a selected text file from sdcard on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10549741/how-to-read-a-selected-text-file-from-sdcard-on-android)

Comment: Throwing random contrasting examples that you've cut and pasted from somewhere (regardless if an online source or your own work) isn't all that helpful with solving the poster's particular problem.