# Requesting Runtime Permission from Custom Dialog in Android

Tags: android, dialog, android-permissions

I am developing an application which shows a custom listview of notes and a Button for adding a new note. When user clicks on button, app shows a full screen dialog to add note with some additional detail. User can also upload an attachment with note as clicking on attachment button. but the problem is after **Android M(API 23)** this task requires runtime permission.

According to [Google Developers](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html), result of permission request will be delivered in `onRequestPermissionsResult()` method. I don't know how can I get this result in method which I used to show fullscreen dialog.

This is how my method looks like:

```
private void showCreateNoteDialog() {

    //create dialog body...
    final Dialog createDialog = new Dialog(NotesActivity.this,R.style.MyFullscreenDialog);
    createDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    createDialog.setContentView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.customdialog_createNote, null));
    createDialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);}
```

**Edit :**

The permission require for uploading a file is **Read from Sd card or External storage**

Comment: You don't need to ask for permissions to show a dialog. Did your app crashed when trying to show a dialog?

Comment: What permission you are trying to ask??

Comment: @SrikarReddy Sorry about my sort description of problem, but i need permission to read from user's sd card to upload attachment with note.

Comment: you can add permission checking in upload file onClickListener

Comment: @Basi, yep, i can add permission in onClickListener. but i can't get result of permission request in listener.

Answer (score 2):

Well the integration of Run time permission can be a lot easier with some useful libraries, my favorite one is [PermissionUtils](https://github.com/rebus007/PermissionUtils).

All you need to do is compile the dependency in app level `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile 'rebus:permission-utils:1.0.3'
}
```

then in `onCreate` of your activity

```
PermissionManager.with(YourActivity.this)
    .permission(PermissionEnum.READ_PHONE_STATE, PermissionEnum.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) // You can put all permissions here
    .askagain(true)
    .ask();
```

and that's it. You can find more information [here](https://github.com/rebus007/PermissionUtils).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

        // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

    } else {

        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is an
        // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
        // result of the request.
    }
}
```

This is how you implement Runtime permission. For more info check the [official developer site](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/index.html). Also, take a look at [Normal and Dangerous Permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous) to know more about which permissions need to be asked at runtime.

Comment: what about getting result ? How to get result back in our method?

Comment: Once the request has been accepted by the user you can read data from the SD card using `FileInputStream`. I hope this helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/10550036/4402462

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get a result straight in you showCreateNoteDialog method, but this is what you can do (pseudo code):

```
showCreateNoteDialog() {
    /* some code goes here */
    if (checkPermission) {
        newMethodCalledFromNoteDialog();
    } else {
        requestPermission();
       // return?
    }
}

newMethodCalledFromNoteDialog() {
        // part of code which needs permission
        // some code depending on previous code
}

onRequestPermissionsResult() {
    if (permissionGranted) {
        newMethodCalledFromNoteDialog();
    }
}
```